# Does it need to be a maven package in Sonatype OSS repository?

Tags: maven, nexus

I want to set up a proxy repository in my nexus sever for an external project that I want to depend on. Does this project have to be in a Sonatype OSS repository, or it can be in any remote repository on the Internet.

I am asking this because I failed to set up a proxy repository in my Nexus server since it is not in a Sonatype OSS repository. My project can't get the necessary artificats when I use my own nexus server to download artificats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Repository Management with Nexus, Table of Contents](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/index.html) starting at chapter 14. for the types of repositories supported:

> 14. OSGi Bundle Repositories
> 15. P2 Repositories
> 16. .NET Package Repositories with NuGet
> 17. Node Packaged Modules and npm Registries
> 18. Ruby, RubyGems and Gem Repositories
> 19. RPM Packages and YUM Repositories

Comment: I want to add this as a proxy repository in my Nexus Server, but I failed. Is it possible? https://github.com/marytts/marytts/blob/master/pom.xml